# python regex xpath - regex an attribute of XPATH

Tags: python, regex, xpath

Given a flexible string of regex pattern, I need to find all attributes attached.

Example string: `/html/body/div[1]/div/a/(@title|@href)`

It needs to return `['@title', '@href']`

I did some research and created a regex pattern like this: `/@\w+/g`

Tried it on regex101 and it did seems to works: https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/9124

But when I coded it in python

```
import re
xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div/a/(@title|@href)"

print(re.findall("/@\w+/g", xpath)) # should have been worked
```

It returns `[]`

As mentioned above, it needs to return `['@title', '@href']`

Did I missed something?

Comment: Python's regex syntax is different. Try this `re.findall("@\w+", xpath)`

Comment: @FailSafe how stupid I am :) you should get the rep. thankyou so much.

Comment: No worries, man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @FailSafe on the question's comment, turns out I need to change the regex pattern from `/@\w+/g` to `@\w+`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try another XPath expression to get the same output

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/a/@*[name()="title" or name()="href"]
```

Comment: I kindly appreaciate your answer. The given input is flexible so the input might be like what you suggested, and then my old regex pattern will not be able to filter it. Something to reconsider for me. Thankyou.